# "Load more" content (Ajax) WITHOUT pagination

Tags: python, python-3.x, scrapy

I would like to scrape a website ( https://www.eventsuche.info/de/eventsuche-innsbruck/1-0.html ). Some content is visible from the beginning. More content is only loaded, if you click on the "more" button.

I checked the network tool, there is no pagination that I could use to easily load more elements.

JavaScript uses a function and it looks like it is setting a cookie to make something possible?

Any ideas how I could load all the elements?

Thank you so much for your help!

Answer (score 0):

Check the "more" button with dev tools and look at the request:
[image]

You can see that the request has a page number option.

Now look for the form in the inspector:
[image]

Use [FormRequest](https://docs.scrapy.org/en/latest/topics/request-response.html?highlight=formrequest#formrequest-objects) to simulate the request (maybe you would like to add the formxpath):

```
scrapy shell https://www.eventsuche.info/de/eventsuche-innsbruck/1-0.html
In [1]: req = scrapy.FormRequest.from_response(response, formdata={'lPageNumber': '2'})

In [2]: fetch(req)
[scrapy.core.engine] DEBUG: Crawled (200) <POST https://www.eventsuche.info/de/eventsuche-innsbruck/1-0.html> (referer: None)

In [3]: view(response)

In [4]: req = scrapy.FormRequest.from_response(response, formdata={'lPageNumber': '3'})

In [5]: fetch(req)
[scrapy.core.engine] DEBUG: Crawled (200) <POST https://www.eventsuche.info/de/eventsuche-innsbruck/1-0.html> (referer: None)

In [6]: view(response)
```

As you can see we get two different pages:
[image]

Just write a function that loop through those pages.