# Scrapy : "Show more results" Ajax

Tags: python, scrapy

I'm trying to parse this kind of page :
[Link here](https://www.cardmarket.com/en/Magic/Cards/Chrome-Mox?language=1&minCondition=2)

It's all good until I need to simulate the "Show more results" button.
I have to say I'm both a beginner in Python and using Scrapy. Also my web skills are really limited.
(so if you have any video / tutorial in order to understand the basics behindz my problem, it would be really appreciated)

Here is my current code :

```
# Partie scraping
import scrapy
import logging
import time
from datetime import datetime
from ..items import CardItem

#Partie générer les URL


class CardsSpider(scrapy.Spider):
    name = "cards"
    allowed_domains = ["cardmarket.com"]
    start_urls = ["https://www.cardmarket.com/en/Magic/Cards/Chrome-Mox?language=1&minCondition=2"]

    def parse(self, response):
        item = CardItem()
        divs = response.xpath("//*[contains(@id, 'articleRow')]")
        
        # [TODO] Passer sur URL des offres
        # [TODO] Gérer offre restreinte
        
        '''
        for a in response.xpath('ul.pager a'):
            logging.warning("Attente de 5 secondes")
            time.sleep(5)
            yield response.follow(a, callback=self.parse)
        '''
        '''
        next_page = response.xpath('//*[@id="loadMoreButton"]/span[2]').click()
        if next_page is not None:
            logging.warning("if nextPage")
            yield response.follow(next_page, self.parse)
        '''

        for div in divs:
            logging.warning(str(datetime.now()) + " here is :" + str(div.getall()))
            item['card'] = 'Chrome Mox'
            item['timestampScraped'] = str(datetime.now())
            item['sellerName'] = div.xpath("div[3]/div/div[1]/span/span/span[3]/a/text()").getall()[0]
            item['set']        = div.xpath("div[3]/div/div[2]/div/div[1]/a[1]/@href").getall()[0] # or use @data-original-title
            item['sellerCountry'] = div.xpath("div[3]/div/div[2]/div/div[1]/span[2]/@data-original-title").getall()[0]
            item['price'] =      div.xpath("div[4]/div[1]/div/div/span/text()").getall()[0].replace(',' , '.').replace(' €' , '')
            item['quantity'] =   div.xpath("div[4]/div[2]/span/text()").getall()[0]

            yield item
```

I've tried different approach, trying to simulate click, etc. But I really don't know what I'm doing.

[Here is the network tab realtive to the button](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oC6cv.png)
But the URL is not "linked" to the one I use... :/

Thanks in advance for your help.

Comment: The content you are trying to scrape is not something that scrapy alone can access, and it doesn't appear that there is any sort of obvious api to extract the information from, which means you will likely need to use some sort of browser automation technology like playwright, selenium  or such

Comment: I would like to keep using scrapy because it was quite easy to use with MongoDb.
In your opinion there is no way to combine scrapy and one of the other technology you mention ?
I saw this post but didn't succeed to do the same in my case : 
[Link to the post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69093031/load-more-content-ajax-without-pagination)

Comment: Yes, sorry that is what I meant, you can use `scrapy-selenium` or `scrapy-playwright` or `scrapy-splash`.  all three of those would probably work for this project.

Comment: Thanks for the precisions. It looks like it's still too high level for me ahah I will have to find a tutorial I think.

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.